# Are there problems using Try or Either for error handling in public/open source Scala APIs?

Tags: scala

I notice that a lot of open-source Scala APIs use `Future` (like Slick) or Java-style exception handling (like spray-json) rather than `Try` or `Either`.

Are there problems returning `Try` or `Either` in simple, open-source APIs that aren't long-running or asynchronous? Should I avoid these and, if so, what should I use instead?

(Obviously, I'd prefer to use core Scala APIs rather than third-party libraries, such as Scalaz, to avoid forcing downstream users to use these libraries as well.)

Comment: I think this is too broad, it depends on your use case, in production applications you may want to use something like `Either` (or I'd rather use `Disjunction`s or `Validation`s) to better handle how to respond to a user.

Comment: @EndeNeu I've updated the question to be more specific: this is about small, simple OSS libraries that aren't long running or need to be async. I'd also prefer to return types in the core library: I don't want my downstream users to have to deal with scalaz unless they want to, for example.

Comment: I think that `Try` and `Either` can have some weird semantics for some uses, although I'm not very sure. For example, I had some trouble in past with the usage of `Try` in for-comprehensions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015495/quick-failure-when-using-for-comprehension-with-scala-util-try) and regarding `Either`, the fact that it's unbiased can also be awkward (http://blog.vngrs.com/right-biased-either-in-scala/). Nevertheless, you can also bundle your own semantics basic on these standard classes.

Comment: @ale64bit what would you use instead?

Comment: As @EndeNeu mentioned, something like scalaz or https://github.com/wix/accord. I believe there are several alternatives. But as for me, I would try to use the standard classes and implement my own semantics. Most of the times, I don't need anything complex, and the aforementioned libs (scalaz specifically) have a cost regarding compilation times in big projects due to implicits.

Answer (score 4):

`Try` is fine for wrapping exceptions for non asynchronous operations.
However, I consider that using an exception instance to return a non-exceptional error condition is not *correct*. I also hold this true when the API is asynchronous and using `Future`. 
Mixing *exceptional* errors with *business* errors easily leads to incorrect/insufficient error handling by the clients of the API (aka by me :) ).

If you decide to still use exceptions to denote your business errors, please remember that exceptions come with a hidden price:  building the stack trace. This can be alleviated if you create your own *business exceptions*  and mix `scala.util.control.NoStackTrace`.

The default `Either` implementation in the Scala standard library is unbiased which means that distinguishing between the success and failure cases relies only on a convention :

> Right is right (correct), therefore Left is wrong (incorrect).

The unbiased side also makes it painful to follow the "happy" path (or to make error recovery stand out)

Your best options at this point (scala 2.11.6 and the corresponding standard library) will vary according to your dependencies and the API you want to expose to your users but it will not be from the scala standard library.

- [Scalaz `Validation`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.1/scalaz_2.11-7.2.1-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.Validation)  or [`\/`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.1/scalaz_2.11-7.2.1-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.$bslash$div)  are an option if you already depend heavily of scalaz
- [Scalactic's `Or` type](http://www.scalactic.org/user_guide/OrAndEvery) is a nice *lightweight* solution if you don't want to pull in the whole scalaz. It is mature and was extracted from scalatest
- (from the comments)[Accord](https://github.com/wix/accord) could be an option but I don't know enough about it to compare it with the others.
- (from the comments)[Cat's Xor](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/xor.html) could be an option but I don't know enough about it to compare it with the others.
- Rapture [`modes`](http://rapture.io/mod/core) can allow you to let the client of the API decide what type he wants to get back (this approach is used in [parboiled2](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2) for instance). I have no idea what the cost is for the library author or for the compilation times though.

You may also already be depending on a library which offers its own `validation` type. For instance, play-json has a JsResult type with validation like abilities. It may make sense to reuse a type depending on what you are working on.

There is a [slip](https://github.com/scala/slip/pull/20) in progress and an [expert group call](https://github.com/scala/slip/issues/5) to add a biased either type to the standard library in Scala. The above 2 solutions have the added benefit of already being able to accumulate errors.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, but I think using non-core Scala API types would be a problem for a public API like this: I'd prefer to hide scalaz from downstream users. And I'm not too bothered about using exceptions as error return types for things like Try or Future.

Comment: I added a note on using business exceptions and mixing in NoStackTrace to lower the performance cost. please use with care as disabling stack trace can make the code hard to debug :)

Comment: interesting NoStackTrace feature, had no idea it existed

Comment: "However, I consider that using an exception instance to return a non-exceptional error condition is not correct" -> you're right, it's not clean; but as long as one creates custom business errors that extend `Throwable`, the exception part is hidden and wouldn't mess up their code. I think it'd be overkill to use an external library just because there is `Exception` in `Try`'s signature.

Comment: Wouldn't you want Scalaz [\/](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.3.0-SNAPSHOT/scalaz_2.11-7.3.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.package) rather than Validation? and a fourth option: cats' [Xor](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/#cats.data.Xor)

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo thanks for the pointer to Xor , I was pretty sure cats would include such a facility but I missed it while skimming the documentation. I usually prefer validation over \/ because it can accumulate multiple errors, but yes \/ can be a viable option.

Comment: @SamyDindane sure as long as you are careful with the stacktrace building. Still for stuff which has both exceptional and business error conditions it means you are likely to handle both in the same code block which I don't find very clean either...

Comment: @Jean "for stuff which has both exceptional and business error conditions it means you are likely to handle both in the same code block" -> Good point. ;)

Comment: The Latin adjective sinister/sinistra/sinistrum originally meant "left" but took on meanings of "evil" or "unlucky" by the Classical Latin era, and this double meaning survives in European derivatives of Latin, and in the English word "sinister". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_and_sinister

Answer (score 2):

**Return a Try[T] when:** there's a semantic difference between a correct result and incorrect result (that is, an error). This because:

- Try is right-biased (it works in map, flatmap, and for-comprehensions).
- The failure case HAS to be a Throwable, and this is important because a throwable will always clearly mean that something is wrong even beyond the boundary of your code.

> **Caveat** : It's true that stack trace generation is an overhead sometimes, but not always! Think twice before prematurely optimizing your code: stack traces carry a lot of useful debug information.
>   Should you later discover you really need to skip stack trace generation, no problem: use `with NoStackTrace` as shown above.

```
def validate(s:String):Try[String] = Option(s).filter(!_.isEmpty).map(Try(_)).getOrElse(new Exception("bad input") with NoStackTrace
```

**Use Either[L,R] when**: both the cases are acceptable, but they are mutually exclusive (i.e. Either[Integer,Float]). For this reason, despite what Scalaz guys have to say about this, I believe it's OK that Either is unbiased.

```
def parseNum(s:String):Either[Int,String] = Try(parseInt(s)).map(Left(_)).getOrElse(Right(s))
```

**Use a Tuple when** similarly to Either, but when you have N, non mutually exclusive values (you know all will be useful)

```
def parseAndReturn(s:String):(Integer,String) = (parseInt(s), s)
```

**Return an Option[T] when** the T can be null, or when you're in the same situation as in a Try[T], but you don't give a s***t about why stuff went wrong.

```
def attemptToparse(s:String):Option[Result] = Try(parse(s)).toOption
```

Comment: About your acceptance of `Either` not being biased: can you expand on what you feel bias would remove for the `Either[Int, Float]` use case? I agree that it's not needed for that scenario, but it *is* needed for others, isn't it?

Comment: Sure: even if the fields of application of an unbiased Either are less, this makes sure that you only use Either when the two types are equally valid for the happy path of your logic.
If the left side of your either does not represent a happy path, you're abusing this tool, and Try is the tool for you (if you care about sticking to standard Scala). If you have a custom error, why don't you extend `Exception with NoStackTrace` and stick to Try?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `Try` is for capture/reifying exceptions, not for returning business/validation errors. Scalaz is a very good alternative, but if you don't want to depend on it, I think `Either` is ok, being unbiased is annoying but not a deal breaker IMHO:
Once you establish the convention that Right is the  valid result, you can "right bias" it with `.rightProjection` (and if you want to deal only with the errors, you can do a left projection.
Another option is to use Either's fold `fold[X](fa: (A) ⇒ X, fb: (B) ⇒ X): X` like `myEither.fold(dealWithErrors _, happyPath _ )` (although it means both `dealWithErrors` and `happyPath` returns the same type)